# C program to calculate type input rather than pre-type

Tags: c, primes, calculation

Im in a bit of a pickle, trying to figure out the way to make my code run based off of input number rather than have them be pre-typed and resulted.

So basically, Id like to input x amount of numbers, and for the program to then calculate biggest prime out of typed numbers.

Thanks!

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int maxprost(int *niz, int vel) {
    int *r = niz, maxcl = 0, i;
    while (niz < r + vel) {
        if (*niz < 2)
            goto dalje;
        for (i = 2; i < *niz; i++) {
            if (*niz % i == 0) {
                goto dalje;
            }
        }
        if (*niz > maxcl) {
            maxcl = *niz;
        }
dalje:;
      niz++;
    }
    return maxcl;
}
int main() {
    int niz[10] = {2, 41, 61, 3712, 4444, 1794, -3311, 7, 8, 1};
    int biggest = maxprost(niz, 10);
    printf("%d Is the biggest number!", biggest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code and fix the formatting.

Comment: btw, whats the point of those `goto` statements? Part of the exercise?

Comment: If you want to read and store some numbers, but you don't know how many there'll be, you basically have two choices: (1) Allocate a big fixed-size array, bigger than the number of inputs you can imagine reading.  Start filling the array, until you receive whatever end-of-input signal you've defined.  Then, keep track (in a separate variable) of how many numbers you actually read, as opposed to the array's size.

Comment: Or, (2) dynamically allocate the input array with `malloc`, meaning that if you read more numbers than you initially allocated space for, you can use `realloc` to make the array bigger.  This is a very standard technique, although it's obviously a bit trickier.  It's not something to do in week 1 of your C career.  But it's a technique you'll want to learn eventually.  There are probably thousands of answers right here on Stack Overflow showing you how to do it.

Comment: @dudesireallyneedurhelp BTW: `for (i = 2; i <= *niz/i; i++) {`: is a lot faster than `for (i = 2; i < *niz; i++) {`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an array if you track the biggest prime with each input number. Just save this biggest prime as long as there is input.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int maxprost(int old_biggest, int candidate) {
    if (candidate < 2) {
        return old_biggest;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < candidate; i++) {
        if (candidate % i == 0) {
            return old_biggest;
        }
    }
    if (old_biggest < candidate) {
        old_biggest = candidate;
    }
    return old_biggest;
}

int main(void) {
    int biggest = 0;
    int candidate;
    while (scanf("%d", &candidate) == 1) {
        biggest = maxprost(biggest, candidate);
    }
    printf("%d is the biggest prime!", biggest);
    return 0;
}
```

Please note that I kept your way of determinating the prime property. There are other and/or better ways, but this is not the issue here.