# read data from txt file into a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, file-io

Hi I am trying to read a comma seprated file into a struct in c. the problem is they have spaces in between the same sentence so fscanf doesnt work well.

Text file:

```
9780136019701,An Introduction to Organic Chemistry,Timberlake Karen,10,3.54,12-2008
9781506304212,Mathematics for Social Scientists,Kropko Jonathan,7,4.73,12-2015
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;
} Date;

typedef struct Book
{
    long long int isbn;
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    int quantity;
    int price;
    Date date;
} Book;

int main() {
    Book* Books;
    int n_books=0;
    FILE *ptr = fopen("Books.txt", "r");

    if(ptr!=NULL) {
        Books = (Book*)malloc(sizeof(Book));

        while(!feof(ptr)) {

            fscanf(ptr,"%lld",&((*(Books+n_books)).isbn));
            fscanf(ptr,"%s",(*(Books+n_books)).title);
            fscanf(ptr,"%s",(*(Books+n_books)).author);
            fscanf(ptr,"%d",&((*(Books+n_books)).quantity));
            fscanf(ptr,"%f",&((*(Books+n_books)).price));
            Date date;
            fscanf(ptr,"%d",&date.month);
            fscanf(ptr,"%d",&date.year);
            (*(Books+n_books)).date = date;

            printf("Name:%s\n",Books[n_books].title);
            printf("ID:%lld\n",Books[n_books].isbn);
            printf("price:%f\n",Books[n_books].price);
            printf("date:%d-%d\n",Books[n_books].date.month,Books[n_books].date.year);
            printf("quantity:%d\n",Books[n_books].quantity);
            printf("author:%s\n",Books[n_books].author);

            n_books++;
            Books=realloc(Books,sizeof(Book)*n_books);
        }

        fclose(ptr);
    }
    else {
        printf("Couldnt load books data");
        exit(0);
    }

    free(Books);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to investigate other format specifiers. [See here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). %99[^,] might be interesting.

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) is worth a read.

Comment: Here's an answer of mine that illustrates a generalized dynamic array implementation: [Creation of Dynamic Array of Strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73737192/5382650) for a similar book implementation.

Comment: @AviBerger i tried it before and it doesn't work

Comment: Just because you have one problem does not mean you do not have more than one problem. I just tried it on a trimmed down and adjusted version of your code. [It does work for your spaces issue.](https://godbolt.org/z/9vnhjs99Y). It doesn't address anything else. @RetiredNinja mentioned another of your code's issues. A third vital issue is that you have to properly move past the delimiting commas in your input stream.

Comment: Not the problem, but: I'd find this code much easier to read and work with if it used normal array notation `fscanf(ptr, "%d", &Books[n_books].quantity);` instead of `fscanf(ptr, "%d", &((*(Books+n_books)).quantity));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has the following issues:

1. The `%s` conversion format specifier will only read a single word.
2. You are using `while(!feof(ptr))`, which is [generally wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/12149471) (and also wrong in this case).
3. You are not skipping the `,` in the input stream.
4. By using `%f`, you are telling `fscanf` to store a `float` into `int price`.
5. The line `Books=realloc(Books,sizeof(Book)*n_books);` will only allocate enough memory for what you are currently using, but you need to allocate enough for what you are currently using **AND** for the next book.

Here is a solution which fixes these issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Date
{
    int year;
    int month;

} Date;

typedef struct Book
{
    long long int isbn;
    char title[100];
    char author[100];
    int quantity;
    double price;
    Date date;

} Book;

int main( void )
{
    Book *Books;
    int n_books = 0;

    FILE *fp = fopen( "Books.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        perror( "fopen" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    Books = malloc( sizeof(Book) );
    if ( Books == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while (
        fscanf(
            fp,
            "%lld,%99[^,],%99[^,],%d,%lf,%d-%d",
            &Books[n_books].isbn,
            Books[n_books].title,
            Books[n_books].author,
            &Books[n_books].quantity,
            &Books[n_books].price,
            &Books[n_books].date.month,
            &Books[n_books].date.year
        )
        == 7
    )
    {
        printf( "Name: %s\n", Books[n_books].title );
        printf( "ID: %lld\n", Books[n_books].isbn );
        printf( "price: %lf\n", Books[n_books].price );
        printf( "date: %d-%d\n", Books[n_books].date.month, Books[n_books].date.year);
        printf( "quantity: %d\n", Books[n_books].quantity);
        printf( "author: %s\n", Books[n_books].author);

        n_books++;
        Books = realloc( Books, sizeof(Book) * (n_books+1) );
        if ( Books == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Memory allocation error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    free(Books);

    fclose( fp );

    return 0;
}
```

For the input specified in the question, this program has the following output:

```
Name: An Introduction to Organic Chemistry
ID: 9780136019701
price: 3.540000
date: 12-2008
quantity: 10
author: Timberlake Karen
Name: Mathematics for Social Scientists
ID: 9781506304212
price: 4.730000
date: 12-2015
quantity: 7
author: Kropko Jonathan
```

However, it is also worth noting that calling `realloc` once per loop iteration is rather inefficient, as `realloc` may have to copy the entire content of the old memory buffer to the new memory location every time. But this will likely only become a problem if you have hundreds or thousands of books. See [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74748660/12149471) for a more efficient algorithm for using `realloc`.